# In an interval do the infinum, supremum, upperbound and lower bound needed to be in the interval

Tags: real-analysis

There are four different parameters for an interval. There are upper bound, lower bound, infinum and supremum. Out of the above four which of them must be within the interval, which may be within the interval and which of them must not be within the interval

Comment: What is "the upper bound" or "the lower bound". There are *infinitely many* upper and lower bounds.

Comment: The infimum is a lower bound and the supremum is an upper bound. But there are other lower bounds, namely everything less than the infimum, and other upper bounds: everything greater than the supremum. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is none. Take $(0,1)$. $\sup (0,1)=1$ and $\inf (0,1)=0$, so neither the $\inf$ nor the $\sup$ are in this set. Since the sup is the least upper bound, any other upper bound is greater than or equal to $1$, and thus cannot be in $(0,1)$. Similarly, any lower bound is less than or equal to $0$ since the inf is the greatest lower bound so these too cannot be in the set.

More generally (if I understand your question), let $I$ be an arbitrary interval, let $U=\sup I$ and $L=\inf I$. Then, IF $U$ or $L$ are in $I$, then it follows that they must be the endpoints. WLOG, suppose $U\in I$. If $U$ is not an endpoint, then there is $s\in I$ such that $s>U$. But $\forall x\in I, x\leq U$ by definition. So $s\leq U<s\Rightarrow s<s$, which is a contradiction.